# Rancher: Container Rancher/Rancher Full Load Memory

Tags: rancher, rancher-rke

Recently we got an error on the rancher where I run the full load memory rancher
My hardware is as follows:
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine
Ram: 8GB
CPU: 4 Core
Disk: 160GB
Below is the rancher container log.

```
2020/11/17 01:44:22 [INFO] Rancher version v2.2.8 is starting
2020/11/17 01:44:22 [INFO] Rancher arguments {ACMEDomains:[domain.com.vn] AddLocal:auto Embedded:false KubeConfig: HTTPListenPort:80 HTTPSListenPort:443 K8sMode:auto Debug:false NoCACerts:false ListenConfig:<nil> AuditLogPath:/var/log/auditlog/rancher-api-audit.log AuditLogMaxage:10 AuditLogMaxsize:100 AuditLogMaxbackup:10 AuditLevel:0}
2020/11/17 01:44:22 [INFO] Listening on /tmp/log.sock
2020/11/17 01:44:22 [INFO] Running etcd --data-dir=management-state/etcd
2020-11-17 01:44:22.415426 W | pkg/flags: unrecognized environment variable ETCD_UNSUPPORTED_ARCH=amd64
2020-11-17 01:44:22.415470 I | etcdmain: etcd Version: 3.2.13
2020-11-17 01:44:22.415477 I | etcdmain: Git SHA: Not provided (use ./build instead of go build)
2020-11-17 01:44:22.415482 I | etcdmain: Go Version: go1.12.9
2020-11-17 01:44:22.415486 I | etcdmain: Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2020-11-17 01:44:22.415491 I | etcdmain: setting maximum number of CPUs to 4, total number of available CPUs is 4
2020-11-17 01:44:22.416492 N | etcdmain: the server is already initialized as member before, starting as etcd member...
2020-11-17 01:44:22.417054 I | embed: listening for peers on http://localhost:2380
2020-11-17 01:44:22.417283 I | embed: listening for client requests on localhost:2379
2020-11-17 01:44:23.418898 W | etcdserver: another etcd process is using "management-state/etcd/member/snap/db" and holds the file lock.
2020-11-17 01:44:23.418924 W | etcdserver: waiting for it to exit before starting...
2020-11-17 01:44:26.640271 I | etcdserver: recovered store from snapshot at index 46900550
2020-11-17 01:44:26.641731 I | mvcc: restore compact to 39291946
2020-11-17 01:44:27.094811 I | etcdserver: name = default
2020-11-17 01:44:27.094842 I | etcdserver: data dir = management-state/etcd
2020-11-17 01:44:27.094849 I | etcdserver: member dir = management-state/etcd/member
2020-11-17 01:44:27.094852 I | etcdserver: heartbeat = 100ms
2020-11-17 01:44:27.094855 I | etcdserver: election = 1000ms
2020-11-17 01:44:27.094859 I | etcdserver: snapshot count = 100000
2020-11-17 01:44:27.094871 I | etcdserver: advertise client URLs = http://localhost:2379
2020-11-17 01:44:38.079712 I | etcdserver: restarting member 8e9e05c52164694d in cluster cdf818194e3a8c32 at commit index 46995188
2020-11-17 01:44:38.096099 I | raft: 8e9e05c52164694d became follower at term 24231
2020-11-17 01:44:38.098270 I | raft: newRaft 8e9e05c52164694d [peers: [8e9e05c52164694d], term: 24231, commit: 46995188, applied: 46900550, lastindex: 46995188, lastterm: 24231]
2020-11-17 01:44:38.115723 I | etcdserver/api: enabled capabilities for version 3.2
2020-11-17 01:44:38.116680 I | etcdserver/membership: added member 8e9e05c52164694d [http://localhost:2380] to cluster cdf818194e3a8c32 from store
2020-11-17 01:44:38.116747 I | etcdserver/membership: set the cluster version to 3.2 from store
2020-11-17 01:44:38.131146 I | mvcc: restore compact to 39291946
2020-11-17 01:44:39.467361 W | auth: simple token is not cryptographically signed
2020-11-17 01:44:39.479838 I | etcdserver: starting server... [version: 3.2.13, cluster version: 3.2]
2020-11-17 01:44:39.921592 I | raft: 8e9e05c52164694d is starting a new election at term 24231
2020-11-17 01:44:39.922338 I | raft: 8e9e05c52164694d became candidate at term 24232
2020-11-17 01:44:39.923179 I | raft: 8e9e05c52164694d received MsgVoteResp from 8e9e05c52164694d at term 24232
2020-11-17 01:44:39.923228 I | raft: 8e9e05c52164694d became leader at term 24232
2020-11-17 01:44:39.923316 I | raft: raft.node: 8e9e05c52164694d elected leader 8e9e05c52164694d at term 24232
2020-11-17 01:44:46.547746 E | etcdserver: publish error: etcdserver: request timed out, possibly due to previous leader failure
fatal error: runtime: out of memory
```

Answer (score 0):

My Rancher is working properly. My idea is to resize the rancher virtual machine giving it more RAM. before, I had to create a snapshot during snapshot creation, my Rancher is working properly @@ I haven't even resized it yet.
I've been having this error for 3 days now, maybe the rancher will fix this by itself